# Git modify remote branch but no git files locally

Tags: git, github

So the situation is weird.

I started a PR with a branch.

Then I had to reset my whole environment, so all Git files locally are gone.

The question is how I checkout my remote branch, make some commits, and push back to that branch in the same PR

I tried many solutions, but none of them work.

Such as check out a new branch from my old branch, and make commits. But now how to push it back to the original branch?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check out a remote branch. Well, you can, but you can't really work coherently that way. What you want to do is make a local branch from the remote branch.

So let's say you've made a new clone of the GitHub repo. And let's say the remote branch is called `mybranch`. And let's say you have no local `mybranch`. Then you would say

```
git fetch
git switch mybranch
```

This creates a local branch `mybranch` starting at the remote branch `origin/mybranch`, and now you have a place to work.

So you work in the usual way, saying `git add` and `git commit` as you go along. When you're all done, you say

```
git push origin mybranch
```

...and the work you've just done is pushed up to the remote and appended to the remote branch, and also appended to the PR at GitHub.

(The push can fail if you have not configured authentication correctly at your end, but I'm assuming you've still got your old configuration on your computer; you didn't say you had to erase your whole hard disk. But if you did, you would need to set up SSH authentication for GitHub on your computer again before pushing.)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. 

Now it works as the normal branch right? So for the next commit I made locally I just need to git add -> git commit -> git push    instead of git push origin mybranch right?

Comment: No, you'll need to say `git push origin mybranch` forever unless you also set the "upstream" on the branch. But I never do. Instead I have a git alias, where `git pp` equates to `git push origin @` which is the same thing only it works for any branch. And `git pp` is even shorter than `git push`! :)

Comment: Thanks. One last question is that what if I need to rebase to the master (main branch) now? Do I just rebase and git push origin mybranch?

Comment: Why would you need to do that?

Comment: the remote mybranch was created from the main branch, and now it has been several days, so I have to rebase the PR/branch to the main branch again, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Who says you "have to"?